# glDeleteTextures causes segfault

Tags: c++, opengl

I have this C++ console application that creates a window and initializes an OpenGL context. 
IDE: CodeBocks
Compilator: MinGW (x32)
OS: Windows 8.1 64bit

So when I compile I have a console and the window with the context. When I close the window first and then the console everything is okay. 
However if I close the console first I get a segmentation fault from glDeleteTextures in the virtual destructor.

Here is how I initialize the texture:

```
texture::texture(const string& fileName)
{
    int width, height, numComponents;
    unsigned char* imageData = stbi_load(fileName.c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);

    if(imageData == NULL)
        cout << "Could not open " << fileName << "." << endl;

    glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE, 0);
    stbi_image_free(imageData);
}

void texture::useTexture(unsigned int textureUnit)
{
    if(textureUnit < 0 || textureUnit > 32)
    {
        cout << "Texture unit not between 0 and 32. Setting it to 0..." << endl;
        textureUnit = 0;
    }

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + textureUnit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
}

texture::~texture()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &m_texture);
}
```

Keep in mind that I wrote the same code, but compiled it with 64bit mingw and used 64bit glfw and it worked just fine... if that helps in any way.

Comment: `However if I close the console first I get a segmentation fault from glDeleteTextures in the virtual destructor.`  So you pulled the rug out from under your application?  Under normal conditions, is that the way you're supposed to stop the application?

Comment: Well, no, but since I did the same and it worked before, then there seems to be something wrong.. I mean it may cause more problems in the fiture and i would prefer to know the reason why this happens anyway... (btw, "rug out from under" :D made me laugh hard)

Comment: Found it! It's because i declare my texture object as "static" so I can initialize it with a function and still have access to it from everywhere. Can someone explain what is happening and why? Is declaring it as static good practice?

Comment: No, that's probably not the best practice (at least not the way you've implemented GL deletion here). The destructor for a static variable will be called at program termination, and by that time you have probably already destroyed your OpenGL context... so calling `glDeleteTextures (...)` in the first place is quite pointless. Consider manually cleaning up your texture when the window closes and adding some logic to prevent calling `glDeleteTextures (...)` more than once (or when `m_texture` is **NULL**).